# Summing up a variable from netCDF data for individual locations in Python

Tags: python, netcdf

I am new to netCDF data and could really use some help. I have a file that contains 365 times (days) and 14052 timeseries. The data spans over a hydrologic year (Sept 13-Aug 14). I am looking for yearly totals at each of the timeseries. I have attached my feeble attempt in python. This gives me the total sum for all cells, but does not split them up based on timeseries.

```
# Imports
import xarray as xr    
import numpy as np

# Read a netCDF file into an xarray Dataset object
ds = xr.open_dataset("Desktop/GOA_discharge_2013_2019/goa_dischargex_09012013_08312014.nc")
 
# Print the contents of the DataSet
print(ds)

# Print the units of the q field
print(ds["q"].units)

# Convert q to a numpy array so that we can take the sum
v = ds["q"].values

# Take the sum of q
sum_13 = np.sum(v)
print("Sum of q_13_14: {}".format(sum_13))
```

###This is what is printed
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:  (time: 365, timeSeries: 14052)
Dimensions without coordinates: time, timeSeries
Data variables:
q        (time, timeSeries) float32 ...
lon      (timeSeries) float32 ...
lat      (timeSeries) float32 ...
year     (time) uint32 ...
month    (time) uint32 ...
day      (time) uint32 ...
Attributes:
title:          Coastal Freshwater Discharge into the Gulf of Alaska
summary:        Coastal FWD was modeled using a suite of physically based...
keywords:       DISCHARGE/FLOW, ALASKA, GULF OF ALASKA
date created:   Dataset created June 2019
creator_name:   David Hill, Professor
creator_email:  dfh@oregonstate.edu
institution:    Oregon State University, Department of Civil Engineering
cubic meters per day
Sum of q_13_14: 807253049344.0

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about your data since they lack descriptions of your time and  timeseries dimensions to make a conclusive answer, but if they are data types which natively support datetime functionality, you may use `xarray.DataArray.groupby('time.year').sum('time')`. You can replace 'time' with 'timeseries' if it supports the data type.